# Javascript Multidimensional JSON Access to data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

i get json data from api like this :

```js
{
    "function": "getCategoryItem",
    "version": "0.1",
    "returnCode": true,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorMessage": "",
    "result": {
        "_ITEM_": [
            {
                "itemId": 10000,
                "itemName": "Item Test\u00fc\u00e7\u011e\u00d6",
                "itemImageURL": "test.png",
                "itemDescription": "21testDESC",
                "itemPrice": 762
            },
            {
                "itemId": 10001,
                "itemName": "Item Test V2",
                "itemImageURL": "tiger.png",
                "itemDescription": "asfdjKDEWSC",
                "itemPrice": 552
            },
                        ],
        "_NAVIGATION_": [
            {
                "itemCount": 21,
                "totalCount": 21,
                "currentPage": 1,
                "navigationSize": 10,
                "pageSize": 10
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But i cant access *ITEM* -> itemId or *NAVIGATION* -> currentPage how can i access inside to *ITEM* and *NAVIGATION* using JavaScript? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add example of the code to show how do you trying to access these properties

Comment: I updated the question, my problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the JSON in the question (if it's really meant to be **JSON**, not just an object literal) is invalid: It has a trailing comma after the first entry in `_ITEM_`, which is valid in JavaScript but not in JSON.

Once that's fixed, and assuming at some stage you *parse* the JSON, at that point it's no longer JSON, its an object with properties (which refer to other objects, etc.). In your case, if `data` refers to the entire parsed result, you'd access `_ITEM_` like this:

```
console.log(data.result._ITEM_[0].itemId); // 10000
```

Live example:

```js
var json =
    '{\n'+
    '    "function": "getCategoryItem",\n' +
    '    "version": "0.1",\n' +
    '    "returnCode": true,\n' +
    '    "errorCode": 0,\n' +
    '    "errorMessage": "",\n' +
    '    "result": {\n' +
    '        "_ITEM_": [\n' +
    '            {\n' +
    '                "itemId": 10000,\n' +
    '                "itemName": "Item Test\u00fc\u00e7\u011e\u00d6",\n' +
    '                "itemImageURL": "test.png",\n' +
    '                "itemDescription": "21testDESC",\n' +
    '                "itemPrice": 762\n' +
    '            },\n' +
    '            {\n' +
    '                "itemId": 10001,\n' +
    '                "itemName": "Item Test V2",\n' +
    '                "itemImageURL": "tiger.png",\n' +
    '                "itemDescription": "asfdjKDEWSC",\n' +
    '                "itemPrice": 552\n' +
    '            }\n' +
    //            ^-- This is where the invalid comma was
    '                        ],\n' +
    '        "_NAVIGATION_": [\n' +
    '            {\n' +
    '                "itemCount": 21,\n' +
    '                "totalCount": 21,\n' +
    '                "currentPage": 1,\n' +
    '                "navigationSize": 10,\n' +
    '                "pageSize": 10\n' +
    '            }\n' +
    '        ]\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '}';
var data = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data.result._ITEM_[0].itemId); // 10000
```

Comment: Can i ask one more question, do you know how can i get count of result, _ITEM_ variables. Like: _ITEM_ = 2; _NAVIGATION_ = 1; result = 2;

Comment: @AhmetÇelikezer: `_ITEM_` and `_NAVIGATION_` are just arrays. Like all arrays, they have a `length` property, e.g.: `data.result._ITEM_.length`. (`result` is a non-array object. They don't have a length. You can get the total number of *own, enumerable* properties it has [well, those with string names, which they will if this was originally JSON] from `Object.keys(result).length`.)

Comment: Okay, that works! thank you so much :)